# Connecting my jhipster project to postgresSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, jhipster

I'm trying to connect my jhipster project with postgresql but I'm getting an error about the password.

Here is the error I'm getting

```
 HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fabrice"
```

I have seen in pgadmin and the password is correct and so is the username  .

My application-dev.yml

```
 datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/fabrice
    username: fabrice
    password: postgres   
    hikari:
      poolName: Hikari
      auto-commit: false
```

This is the postgres users photos:

[image]

I think this was what you wanted :

```
CREATE ROLE fabrice WITH
  LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'md576436d4007f2e5338a99e5a76181a7a4';
```

Comment: Your connection string is? Your pg_hba.conf settings are?

Comment: postgres   this is my password

Comment: What we need is the entire connection string you are using. Also how you are calling it in `jhipster` would be helpful. I'm guessing `postgres` is the password for the `postgres` user. You are connecting as `fabrice` user. Have you set up that user with password?

Comment: Did you get what you wanted ?

Comment: So did you give the `fabrice` role it's own password? I'm thinking you did and that it is not 'postgres', hence the error message.

Comment: It was just the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the port used by postgreSql it was 5433 instead of 5432 .So for the others persons you may check the port used by postgresql

Comment: If it was just the port you would have gotten a different message. It would seem you have two instances of Postgres running one on 5432 and one on 5433. The one at 5432 did not have the password for `fabrice`.  You probably ought to sort that out before you go any further.

Comment: I didn't know I had two instances of Postgres but I you are right at any point You guess it correctly I had two instances of Postgres one at 5432 and the other one at 5433 .Thank you very much .Sorry for have disturbed you